# One base to rule them all. One base to bring them all and in the darkness bind them

Tags: c++, inheritance, gcc

Is it possible to write a universal base class which all other classes (except it) publicly and virtually inherit?  (Is there a workaround for gcc?).  It would be preferable to not explicitly inherit...because I want the standard library stuff to inherit from this also....And is this wise to do?

If you down vote please explain why (I do believe this is a legitimate question even if it is a stupid thing to do, which it might be, but that is part of the question)

Comment: Without explicitly saying so? Are you from Java?

Comment: @LukeLee Without explicitly saying (and no I am not from Java)....I want this to affect even the standard library stuff

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Nayuki Mostly just curious

Answer (score 6):

Trying to shoehorn in a common virtual base would break C++ badly.

There are a number of language rules that allow special treatment for *standard-layout* and *trivially copyable* types.  Classes with a virtual base class qualify for neither of these.

Even other systems which purportedly have a common base class (e.g. Microsoft's .NET) have some blit-able types for which inheritance from the base class is a convenient lie -- virtual dispatch is not permitted, all calls relating to inherited members of these classes must be resolved at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Define a class with a public virtual destructor.  Call it `base`.

Now after each class `foo` do this:

```
class foo:
  public virtual base
```

And done!

Naturaly this only works on your own types.  If you want to enforce it on other types, such as `std`, simply reimplement `std` in your own `notstd` namespace type by type and inherit all types from your `base`.  Similarly for any third party libraries you want to use: some may prove impractical.

Note that this can change the binary layout of the class, and change what guaratees exist: no such class `foo` is standard layout, for example.

On the other hand, if you want a new language that behaves mostly like C++, but forces a base class on all classes, and disntinguishes classes from structs, consider [java](/questions/tagged/java).

Comment: But he wants more...

Comment: To answer the "more" part, secretly `sed` before `gcc` (by defining a function) to make all the classes inherit from `foo` :)

Comment: @axiom This sounds like a man of experience in this area

Comment: I sense... sarcasm. Yes. Sarcasm this answer has. Hmmmm... Strong in the sarcasm this is. Very strong.